# Add taxonomy combinations to YOAST sitemap

Tags: php, wordpress

Used rewrite rules to achieve the current url setup but I need these combinations also added to the sitemap. 'collection' is just a product attribute with the taxonomy of `pa_collection`

Current URL Setup

`https://*****.com/collection/%COLLECTION-TERM%/product-tag/%PRODUCT-TAG-TERM%`

```html
<?php

/**
 *  Create a new custom yoast seo sitemap
 */
 
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_index', 'ex_add_sitemap_custom_items' );
add_action( 'init', 'init_wpseo_do_sitemap_actions' );
// Add custom index
function ex_add_sitemap_custom_items(){
 global $wpseo_sitemaps;
 $date = $wpseo_sitemaps->get_last_modified('CUSTOM_POST_TYPE');
 $smp ='';
     $smp .= '<sitemap>' . "\n";
 $smp .= '<loc>' . site_url() .'/CUSTOM_KEY-sitemap.xml</loc>' . "\n";
 $smp .= '<lastmod>' . htmlspecialchars( $date ) . '</lastmod>' . "\n";
 $smp .= '</sitemap>' . "\n";
 return $smp;
}
function init_wpseo_do_sitemap_actions(){
 add_action( "wpseo_do_sitemap_CUSTOM_KEY", 'ex_generate_origin_combo_sitemap');
}
function ex_generate_origin_combo_sitemap(){
 global $wpdb;
 global $wp_query;
 global $wpseo_sitemaps;
        $post_type = 'archive';
 wp_reset_query();
 $args = array(
  'posts_per_page'   => -1,
  'orderby'          => 'post_date',
  'order'            => 'DESC',
  'post_type'        => $post_type,
  'post_status'      => 'publish',
  'suppress_filters' => true
 );
 query_posts( $args );
 wp_reset_postdata();
 //echo '<pre>';print_r($url);echo '</pre>';
 $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
 $output = '';
 if( !empty( $posts_array ) ){
  $chf = 'weekly';
  $pri = 1.0;
  foreach ( $posts_array as $p ) {
   $p->post_type   = $post_type;
   $p->post_status = 'publish';
   $p->filter      = 'sample';
   $url = array();
   if ( isset( $p->post_modified_gmt ) && $p->post_modified_gmt != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' && $p->post_modified_gmt > $p->post_date_gmt ) {
    $url['mod'] = $p->post_modified_gmt;
   } else {
    if ( '0000-00-00 00:00:00' != $p->post_date_gmt ) {
     $url['mod'] = $p->post_date_gmt;
    } else {
     $url['mod'] = $p->post_date;
    }
   }
   $url['loc'] = site_url().'/sample/all/'.$p->post_name;
   $url['chf'] = $chf;
   $url['pri'] = $pri;
   $output .= $wpseo_sitemaps->sitemap_url( $url );
   // Clear the post_meta and the term cache for the post, as we no longer need it now.
   // wp_cache_delete( $p->ID, 'post_meta' );
   // clean_object_term_cache( $p->ID, $post_type );
  }
 }
 // Grab last modified date
 $sql  = $wpdb->prepare(" SELECT MAX(p.post_modified_gmt) AS lastmod
  FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
  WHERE post_status IN ('publish') AND post_type = %s ", $post_type );
 $mod = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
 // Generate terms URLs
 $practitioner_terms = get_terms( 'pa_collection', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
 $practitioner_termss = get_terms( 'product_tag', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );

 if( !empty( $practitioner_terms ) ){
  $pri = 1;
  $chf = 'weekly';
  foreach ($practitioner_terms as $key => $term ){
   $url = array();
   $url['loc'] = site_url().'/collection/'.$term->slug.'/product-tag/';
         $url['pri'] = $pri;
         $url['mod'] = $mod;
         $url['chf'] = $chf;
         $output .= $wpseo_sitemaps->sitemap_url( $url );
  }
  foreach ($practitioner_termss as $key => $term ){
   $url = array();
   $url['loc'] = site_url().'/product-tag/'.$term->slug;
         $url['pri'] = $pri;
         $url['mod'] = $mod;
         $url['chf'] = $chf;
         $output .= $wpseo_sitemaps->sitemap_url( $url );
  }
 }
```

This is the section is where I need to combine the taxonomies. So far I have all the terms for both taxonomies on the same page but I need to have them combined to create all the possible combinations.

```
$practitioner_terms = get_terms( 'pa_collection', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
$practitioner_termss = get_terms( 'product_tag', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' ); 

if( !empty( $practitioner_terms ) ){
    $pri = 1;
    $chf = 'weekly';
    foreach ($practitioner_terms as $key => $term ){
        $url = array();
         $url['loc'] =site_url().'/collection/'.$term>slug.'/product-tag/';

            $url['pri'] = $pri;
            $url['mod'] = $mod;
            $url['chf'] = $chf;
            $output .= $wpseo_sitemaps->sitemap_url( $url );
    }
    foreach ($practitioner_termss as $key => $term ){
        $url = array();
        $url['loc'] = site_url().'/product-tag/'.$term->slug;
            $url['pri'] = $pri;
            $url['mod'] = $mod;
            $url['chf'] = $chf;
            $output .= $wpseo_sitemaps->sitemap_url( $url );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution that works, could possibly be useful to others...

```
$practitioner_terms = get_terms( 'pa_collection', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
$practitioner_termss = get_terms( 'product_tag', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );

if( !empty( $practitioner_terms ) ){
    $pri = 1;
    $chf = 'weekly';
    foreach ($practitioner_terms as $key => $term ){
        foreach ($practitioner_termss as $key => $terms ){
        $url = array();
        $url['loc'] = site_url().'/collection/'.$term->slug.'/product-tag/'.$terms->slug;
            $url['pri'] = $pri;
            $url['mod'] = $mod;
            $url['chf'] = $chf;
            $output .= $wpseo_sitemaps->sitemap_url( $url );

    }

    }

}
```